# Not seen my account for 18 months +

Tags: assets, xlm, wallets

Does anyone know how to get my coins back from the old Stellar Lumen wallet? I haven't realised what has been going on so the site isn't the same anymore and I don't know how to access them via the ledger.

Can anyone help? Are the coins still there or are they lost for good?

I used to just open the website and access via the ledger, but now it's all changed.